# How Store datetime value in to local datetime variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am stored some value in to `session`. And retrieve some column `datetime` value with where clause and use this `session` value.
Code:

```
 DateTime Currentdate = default(DateTime);
 Session["d_id"] = dt.Rows[0]["d_id"];
 Currentdate = objdl.GetScalerValue("select IsNull(Max(LoginDate),GETDATE()) from             
               q_logintrack_panel where Id= '" + Session["d_id"].ToString() + "'");
```

Here its produce error at 3rd row.

```
Error: string can not be explicitely convert into system.Datetime.
```

So please give me the exact solution please...

Comment: The method GetScalerValue returns a String, but should return a DateTime. You can assign the return value to a String first and use DateTime.Parse to obtain a DateTime type.

Comment: Show us what is returned by GetScalerValue().

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse string returned by GetScalarValue to a DateTime object:

```
DateTime Currentdate = default(DateTime);
Session["d_id"] = dt.Rows[0]["d_id"];
var dtStr = objdl.GetScalerValue("select IsNull(Max(LoginDate),GETDATE()) from q_logintrack_panel where Id= '" + Session["d_id"].ToString() + "'");
Currentdate = DateTime.Parse(dtStr);
```